# callback functions error in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I am learning about callback functions. I can't find why there is a difference between these two code blocks. Can somebody explain this?

```
function a(callback) { 
  var something = 10; 

  callback(); 
} 

a(function() { 
  console.log(something); 
});
```

And this:

```
function a() { 
  var something = 10; 

  (function() { 
    console.log(something); 
  }());
} 

a();
```

I am also confused about these two code blocks:

```
var clientData = {
  id: 094545,
  fullName: "Not Set",
  setUserName: function (firstName, lastName) {

    var self = this;
    self.fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
    console.log(self);
  } }



function getUserInput(firstName, lastName, callback) {

    callback (firstName, lastName);
}

getUserInput('viet','nguyen',clientData.setUserName );
console.log(clientData.fullName);
// It will return the window object and not set
```

And this:

```
function getUserInput() {

    clientData.setUserName('viet','nguyen')
}
getUserInput();
console.log(clientData.fullName);
// it will return the object clientData and the fullname set to viet nguyen
```

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude He's asking for an explanation, not a code review.

Comment: be nice to OP, us newbies need to learn the ropes and feel welcomed in the community :)

Comment: @Tresdin that's why I think he needs a code review. Maybe I'm mistaken, but stackoverflow is to solve specific errors in code, not to explain how some code works

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Code Review isn't for code explanation either.

Comment: All of you are wrong. Stackoverflow is not for this kind of questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic . Ontopic: `a specific programming problem, or
    a software algorithm, or
    software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
    a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development`

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Please take a look at the on-topic help centres for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) before making such a recommendation again. There are at least 3 rules for migration: Don't migrate crap, it has to be off-topic at the original site, it has to be on-topic for the target site. This isn't crap, but I'll leave it to you to figure out what the answer to the other 2 questions is.

Comment: You are passing a function which acts as a callback, this means that your CallBack behavior may vary depending on the function that you've supplied as an argument. Think of it as sort of like events.

Comment: This question would benefit from adding more research effort by OP. As it currently stands, it's simply a mediocre question.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Learn to read! It's specifically off-topic!

Comment: That's really ambiguous, because this is ontopic: **Do I want feedback about any or all facets of the code?** So this kind of questions fits with codereview. Even if not fits with codereview, is obvious doesn't fit in stackoverflow.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Specifically listed on that help center topic, under the description of off-topic questions: "Trouble-shooting, debugging, or **understanding code snippets**" (emphasis mine). This question is **specifically** off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude No! No! No! Asking about understanding snippets is listed specifically as off-topic at Code Review. There is no ambiguity. Please stop confusing the OP. One of the close reasons is: "Questions must involve real code that you own or maintain. Pseudocode, hypothetical code, or stub code should be replaced by a concrete implementation. Questions seeking an explanation of someone else's code are also off-topic."

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude That would be true, if the OP wanted feedback on the code. As this question stands, the OP wants an **explanation** on the code, which is not the same. The fact of the matter is: this question would be immediately closed on Code Review.

Comment: Does anyone have a suggestion as to where this type of question _should_ be posted? Seems like a reasonable question to try to understand what's happening with the code. I'm not saying it necessarily belongs on Stack Overflow, but there should be somewhere for it to live.

Comment: @redbmk The assumption that every question has a place where it's on-topic is flawed.

Comment: @Mast, It's not an assumption, more of an observation. Maybe it doesn't have a place on stack exchange, but I still think it's a valid question in general. Perhaps OP is taking a class at school and learning about closures - in which case they might want to ask their teacher or tutor. But perhaps OP is learning this on their own through samples on the internet, has been stumped after hours of hacking away. If there's nowhere to ask this type of question, maybe there should be. For all I know though, OP is trying to cheat on their homework - who knows...

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude this question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see [How to ask “how to understand some code” questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7514/31260). Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**. Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with

Comment: I am newbie to JS and stackoverflow either. I am learning on my own so that i am appreciate all the comments and answers here, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an explanation of your first code-block pair:

1. when you pass a function as an argument from a caller to a receiving function (callee), the recipient function can call that "callback function" however it is defined.
2. when you define a function in the callee function, then that is the only way it can operate -as a "static sub-routine", as opposed to the above where it can be what-ever and where-ever it is defined from any caller's arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Often an application will need to execute many functions and most of the times in sequence, say you have a register function but when that is successful you want to direct the user to the next step. So here we can call a function once called register() and when that function is done it will automatically call the function we want it to execute on success, alternatively nowadays it has also became common to use multiple callbacks.

Now in these cases many use it to call either or on success or failure. When using these you can pass 2 functions one that will show the success message or the other which shows the error. Example below

```
function register(onsuccess, onfailure) {
    try {
        ... Some logic here ...
        onsuccess();
    }
    catch(err) {
        onfailure();
    }
}
```

using the other method that doesn't use callbacks we have to do this

```
function register() {
    try {
        ... Some logic here ...
        return true;
    }
    catch(err) {
        return false;
    }
}

if (register()) {
    ... onsuccess logic goes here ...
} else {
    ... onfailure logic goes here ...
}
```

as you can see the callback method is easier to read and also easier to debug and maintain.

Hope this has answered your question and clears those concerns you may had :)

EDIT: I also wanted to mention that when using Callback function it is always easier for you the programmer to create conditionals to execute that callback.

Answer (score 0):

> // It will return the window object and not set

This is because the execution context changes when function reference is passed as an argument.

This line

```
getUserInput('viet','nguyen',clientData.setUserName );
```

is executed in the global context (`window`), not in the context of `clientData` hence any argument passed is passed in the context of `caller`.

As per the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist)

> Let callerContext be the running execution context.

In this case callerContext is `window`.

Answer (score 0):

These are two separate issues.

### First pair of code snippets

The problem is the scope of the variables. In this function, you declare a [variable (var)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) `something` inside function `a`. The callback that gets passed into `a` is declared outside the scope of `a` and therefore doesn't know anything about `something`, since `something` was locally scoped and not a global.

```
function a(callback) { 
  var something = 10; // This is a local variable

  callback();
} 

a(function() { 
  console.log(something); // What is `something`??? 
});
```

To fix it you could pass `something` into the callback like this:

```
function a(callback) { 
  var something = 10; // This is still a local variable

  callback(something);
} 

a(function(whatever) { 
  // `whatever` is a new local variable that references `something`.
  console.log(whatever);
});
```

With the other version of this function you had written, `something` is defined in the function because it is defined within the `a` function, making it a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). It's therefore a closureIt can be handy to have closures, but if you're writing a function that depends on a callback it's likely asynchronous and the callback would be defined elsewhere, so it would be better to pass the data in as an argument.

```
function a() { 
  var something = 10; 

  (function() { // This is a closure
    console.log(something); // The same `something` defined above
  }());
} 

a();
```

It can be handy to have closures, but if you're writing a function that depends on a callback it's likely asynchronous and the callback would be defined elsewhere, so it would be better to pass the data in as an argument.

### Second pair of code snippets

When you call a function, an implicit [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is passed in. Calling `clientData.setUserName()` is roughly equivalent to saying `clientData.setUserName.call(clientData)`. The first argument passed into [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is the object that will be assigned to `this`. However, if you pass the function `clientData.setUserName` to something as a callback, and call that function, it's more equivalent to saying `clientData.setUserName.call(this)`, where `this` is no longer `clientData` (unless you were calling another function on `clientData`). If `this` hasn't been overridden, it will refer to the global object. In a web browser, that will be `window`. One possible solution is to use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to override what `this` will be when the function is called:

```
function getUserInput(firstName, lastName, callback) {
  callback(firstName, lastName);
}

getUserInput('viet','nguyen',clientData.setUserName.bind(clientData));
```

Another possible solution would be to pass in `clientData` in the callback, although it's a less robust solution as it means `getUserInput` would always use `clientData` rather than letting the caller decide:

```
function getUserInput(firstName, lastName, callback) {
  callback.call(clientData, firstName, lastName);
}

getUserInput('viet','nguyen',clientData.setUserName);
```

Comment: thanks for your help, i know i could use bind or call but i want to change a little bit, that's it

Comment: Well, you said you were confused about the second pair of code blocks, so I was just trying to explain why you're not seeing what you expect for `this` in one snippet versus the other. Another possible solution would be to have the function in `clientData` refer to itself as `clientData` instead of `this`.